# Walking through directory path

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to list all the directories (one level below /home/ dir) and it's contents. This code is working but when I convert the dictionary to pandas dataframe, the directory name does not match with file names.

```
mypath='/home/'
from os import walk

myd=dict()
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    for i in dirnames:
        for (dirpath1, dirnames1, filenames1) in walk(i):
            myd[i]=','.join(filenames1)


import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(myd , index=[0]).T
df.columns=['files']

pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)
df
```

Is there better way to build 2 column dataframe with directory and it's file contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your end result should look like, but [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) does the full recursion for you! There is no need to iterate over the `dirnames` in a second loop:

```
import os

mypath = '/home/'

myd = {}
for (here, dirs, files) in os.walk(mypath):
    for file in files:
        myd[here] = '.'.join(files)

print(myd)
```

This is python 3 code; it python 2 `file` is a keyword and should not be used as variable name...

**UPDATE**

if you only need one level below the input directory there is no need to `walk`:

```
myd = {}
for name in os.listdir(mypath):
    subdir = os.path.join(mypath, name)
    if not os.path.isdir(subdir):
        continue
    myd[name] = '.'.join(os.listdir(subdir))

print(myd)
```